# ReactJS version 15.6.2: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I am facing below error and I have no luck in resolving the same. I went through many answers for same issue in Stack Overflow but none of them helping me resolve the issue.

I am using ReactJS v15.6.2, babel-loader 7 and webpack 4.15.0

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>    
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch" rel="stylesheet">
</head>    
<body>
    <div id="App">
        <!-- this is where the root react component will get rendered -->
    </div>
    <script type="javascript" src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="javascript" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/80fe1399d9.js"></script>
    <script type="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> . 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My entry component App.js

```
render(<Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route path="/" component={App} >

  </Route>
  <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
</Router>, document.getElementById('App'))
```

Comment: Where did you place the script in your html? At the end of your body (still inside), add the script: `<script src="./App.js"></script>`

Comment: I updated my question. I placed it in below the dev tag inside body. But I am facing the same issue even if my index.html doesn't contain any scripts

Comment: @HemadriDasari only possible issue is that `document.getElementById('App')` is undefined. What does `console.log(document.getElementById('App'))` show?

Comment: @m0meni I placed console.log(document.getElementById('App')) before render method. It gives me null

Comment: Hey sorry I did stupid mistake. I added html-webpack-plugin twice in my webpack config. Its working fine now after removing one.

Comment: add an answer so that it is closed

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay I have added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue because I added html-webpack-plugin twice in my webpack config. The issue got resolved post removing duplicates.